# Better way to write this code in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am working on a project and at the same time learning.
I have written code in the past using Matlab and C.

For this project in Ruby I am saving variables in arrays, which is common for me but somehow I think this is not a good idea using Ruby.

That's why I require from your help.

Do you have a better idea how to write the following for loop? I don' want to repeat code (I want to use DRY principle) and I think there should be a better way to shorten the code.

```
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco4 = Array.new()
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco6 = Array.new()
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco8 = Array.new()
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco10 = Array.new()
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco12 = Array.new()
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco14 = Array.new()
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco16 = Array.new()


for i in 0..19
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco4[i] = (autarkie_eco4 / 100) * jahrstromverbrauch
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco6[i] = (autarkie_eco6 / 100) * jahrstromverbrauch
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco8[i] = (autarkie_eco8 / 100) * jahrstromverbrauch
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco10[i] = (autarkie_eco10 / 100) * jahrstromverbrauch
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco12[i] = (autarkie_eco12 / 100) * jahrstromverbrauch
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco14[i] = (autarkie_eco14 / 100) * jahrstromverbrauch
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco16[i] = (autarkie_eco16 / 100) * jahrstromverbrauch
end
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should probably think about how you store your data before thinking about how you can make the code look better.

Comment: Are you sure populating an array with 20 exactly the same elements is wise? For the multiple variables use a collection, like a `Hash`.

Comment: Digits in variable names are already a sign of something odd going on. Most of the time.

Comment: If i was you i would take a step back and describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than saying "here's a load of code which doesn't really make sense, how do i improve it?".  We don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: I do not know why I got down voted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would be better holding the data like so:

```
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco = {
  4 => {
    1 => <val a>,
    2 => <val b>,
    etc
  6 => {
    1 => <val c>,
    2 => <val d>,
    etc
  },
  etc
}
```

Then, your code will have things like

```
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco[8][3]
```

instead of

```
strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco8[3]
```

This way you have a single variable holding the data, instead of loads of variables with numbers in their names, which is usually a bad idea.

you can do this like so:

```
autarkie_eco = {4 => <val a>, 6 => <val b>, 8 => <val c>, etc - set this in your code however}

strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco = {}
eco_values = [4,6,8,10,12,14,16]
eco_values.each do |eco_value|
  for i in 0..19
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco[eco_value] ||= {}
    strombezugsvermeidung_kWh_a_eco[eco_value][i] = autarkie_eco[eco_value]/100 * jahrstromverbrauch
  end
end
```

I don't know your codebase, just guessing, but you might want to further move data from out of variable names and into the variable value by having something like

```
strombezugsvermeidung[:kWh][:a][:eco][8][3] => val
```

Comment: Great, I never thought about hashes.